# How to ajax request send with default date in datepicker during page loading and then send ajax on changing the date

Tags: jquery, ajax, datepicker

I want ajax request should send at page loading with default date

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#schedule_datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'}).datepicker("setDate", new Date()).on("change", function () {
        var dataTable = $('.table-wrap').DataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "bDestroy": true,
            "ajax":{
                url: '<?php echo TEMPLATES_URI."schedule_ajax.php"; ?>',
                type: "post",
                data:{date_time:$('#schedule_datepicker').val()},
                error: function(){ 
                    $(".employee-grid-error").html("");
                    $("#employee-grid").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th   colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
                    $("#employee-grid_processing").css("display","none");   
                }
            }
        });     
    });
```

With new date ajax request should send

Comment: if you want it at page ready why use ajax?

Comment: I want to display records on default date also

Comment: why do you need ajax for that?

Comment: `$('#schedule_datepicker').trigger('change');` But you shouldn't really need Ajax for this

Comment: to diplay records

Comment: then how the record wil display without ajax

Comment: Actually, when page refresh, then only default date shown in datepicker but no record shown in datatable. Record shows when I select any date from date picker. record should be display on default date when page refresh.

Comment: Change logic on server side script to take today date as default date if date is empty.